# Sudo permissions error

Tags: permissions, sudo, xampp

I am getting the following error:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host XXX
sudo: /etc/sudoers is mode 0666, should be 0440
Segmentation fault
```

To start xampp, I typed

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Please help. How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you just installed Ubuntu? Make sure you've installed Ubuntu on a EXT filesystem (e.g. ext4). Please post the output of `mount` and `cat /etc/sudoers`. File permissions 666 is not good, it allows anyone to read and write to the file.

Comment: /etc/sudoers having a mode of 666 is an indication of a serious security issue. Your system may have been compromised.

Answer (score 3):

To solve this issue you will have to boot into recovery mode (root shell) and set the appropriate permissions on that file.

1. To boot into recovery mode hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> while booting.
2. Select the first entry ending with `(recovery mode)`.
3. In the recovery menu list select the `root` option.
4. Run following command.

   ```
   chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers
   ```
5. Enter `reboot` when you are done.

That should work.