# permission error on Ubuntu?

Tags: permissions, sudo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sudo permissions error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29511/sudo-permissions-error)

Hi,

I am getting the following error:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host XXX
sudo: /etc/sudoers is mode 0666, should be 0440
Segmentation fault
```

To start xampp, I typed

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Please help, How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: The permissions of this file do not change by itself. If you have not changed the permissions yourself, you could have executed a malicious script as root and have more worries.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following :

```
1.sudo gedit /etc/hosts
2.if ip address and hostname not there please write them and save the file.
```

Please feed us back if you still facing same problem !

Comment: and you can change permission by: `sudo chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers`

Comment: that will not work. You cannot fix sudo with sudo. The user needs to boot in recovery mode in order to set the right permissions.

Comment: @Lekensteyn , you write user need boot from live cd and mount the partition that include file system and changed the partition ...sorry :)

Comment: No, I meant the user should hold SHIFT to get the GRUB2 menu and choose "Recovery mode" instead of the usual boot entry. From there, choose "Root prompt" and run `chmod 440 /etc/sudoers`. (note that 0440 and 440 are the same thing)